# Sharepoint REST API GetFileByServerRelativeUrl when there's # sign in the file name

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a problem getting file from Sharepoint using REST API when there's # sign in the file name, I escape it to %23, but response is file not found (404). Looking on:
https://dev.office.com/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business-apis-to-support-and-in-file-names

And they explain that GetFileByServerRelativeUrl API will not support # and % signs, but there's no explanation how work in REST API with files that has # in the file name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, even though Microsoft has already [introduced a support for special characters](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/New-support-for-and-in-SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for/ba-p/60357), [`SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246729.aspx) fails when file name contains `#` character (no matter whether `#` is escaped to `%23` or not)

But you could consider the following endpoint to retrieve file properties instead:

```
Url: http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/folders/getbyurl(folderrelativeurl)/files/getByUrl(url)
Method: GET
```

For example:

```
var folderUrl = "Shared Documents";
var fileName = "Guide #123.docx";

var requestUrl = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/folders/getbyurl('${encodeURIComponent(folderUrl)}')/files/getByUrl('${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}')`;
$.getJSON(requestUrl)
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data.Name);
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Actually I found the way : /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=@f)/$value?@f='_/site/lib/file_' and # should be escaped to %23 it's working.

Comment: @SlavaG Could you post it as a distinct answer so that to highlight the solution for future visitors? Thank you (or anyone else)